# creating timeseries graph with flot chart with option view graph in selected time formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to create a timeseries graph using flotcharts http://www.flotcharts.org/ and i am trying to add the option for the user to selected time formats for displaying data like yearly or monthly or daily formats. But i couldnt find a live example in flotcharts having this feature. I was wondering the foltcharts has this as built in feature or will i have to write this feature separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [this example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time) does most of what you're looking for.

Comment: The core idea is that you're re-plotting using a new set of options, with a new date range, scale, and format.  You can use whatever values you like.